# Hyperlinking a piece of text in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

I'm using Excel 2010 and I have a simple problem where I need to hyperlink a certain part of my text. My cell content is as simple as "For blablabla, click here." I want to add a hyperlink to the "here".

Does anyone know how can I do this?

Comment: Actually, you can't. The link gets applied to the whole cell (even with a formula using `HYPERLINK`). You could try to embed an object in the cell but that would probably be overkill.

Answer (score 30):

I think Excel does not allow creating hyperlinks on only part of the text in a cell.
The hyperlink can only be set on the complete cell.

But there is something you can do.
You can make "here" look like hyperlink and the rest of the text look normal.

How to do it? Just get into the cell in edit mode (Press F2), select the text "For blabla.."; remove its underline and change the color to black.

This way you will have a visual feel of just "here" being a hyperlink but the other text will remain "clickable"! :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did not work for me, when I pressed enter to leave the cell, Excel made the whole content a link again.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid That's weird because it [worked for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j18g7.png). I wonder what's different in our setups. I tested it in Win7 with Excel 2013.

Comment: Works fine - thanks.   You can keep the hyperlink part alone, and only change the "text" part(s) to anything you want. Just select the text part(s) in the formula edit line and then right mouse...format cells....

Answer (score 15):

There is a way to hyperlink only certain text in one single cell.

```
="For blablabla, click "&=HYPERLINK("http://example.domain.com/link/to/open/index.html", "here")
```

What this does is make some text (For blablabla, click), and then adds a hyperlink to the end of the sentence (here). The result should look something like:

For blablabla, click [here](http://example.domain.com/link/to/open/index.html)

Comment: The second = before HYPERLINK is not allowed in a formula. When remofing it, the whole text is changed to a hyperlink.

Answer (score 9):

I add a shape (rectangle) that just covers the text I want the hyperlink on and then set:
Fill: No fill
Line Color: No line

Then I add hyperlink to the shape.

I have used this method in power points and it appears to work in Excel also.

Answer (score 6):

OK, this a solution to this old question but it's not one that I would personally use. It's a cheat. I have not seen a single method with code or in the UI that allows HTML or RTF to fully render in a cell, and have not seen any examples with multiple links. So I don't think it's possible yet. However, here is a close work-around...

As suggested earlier, use Word to create your text, but use Word hyperlinks, not bookmarks.

[image: In Word]

Select that text, copy, and in Excel use Paste Special to paste it where you want to see it as a Word Object.

[image: Excel Paste Special as Word Object]

Now resize so that it fits with other cells.

[image: Looking more natural]

Here's the kinda icky part. You need to triple-click the object in order to render it as a Word "document" within the cell, and thus be able to click any of the contained links.

[image: Word Object]

You cannot sort or filter on this field, nor can you do calculations based on the text. The object is not actually in a cell, it's just an overlay above the sheet. However, right click and go to Format Object and Properties, and you can "nail" the object to it's location above a specific cell so that it moves along with the cell, giving the appearance of being "in" that cell.

[image: Fix the position]

And the finished product:

[image: Final]

Answer (score 5):

It can be done...

Assuming you have your excel file open, open a Word document.  Type the text that you want to link to.  (you will copy and paste this text into a cell in your excel file.)

After generating your desired text in the word document:

1. Select the text (portion) you want to link to.
2. On the Insert tab, in the Links group, click Bookmark.
3. Under the bookmark name type a name for your Bookmark such as a topic name. (no spaces but underscores allowed.)
4. Click Add
5. Copy all of the text from the word document and paste it into your excel document (cell).
6. Select the cell where you want to create a link to this new text
7. Click Hyperlink
8. On the left hand menu select "Place in this document"
9. In the window to the right, you will see your Bookmark under "Defined Names"

[image]

This will take you to the text in the cell that you pasted.

Updated.  You can rename the Link in the top "Text to Display" Entry.

Comment: I don't know which MS Office version you have but it does not work in 2007.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem too, and what I did was just add columns before and after the hyperlink and made them appear to be one cell.

Answer (score 1):

Old post just ran across this so it may be too old now - but when I need to put multiple text hyperlinks in the same cell then I use individual textboxes for each link.  I format the text to look like a hyperlink, assign  it to where it needs to go, and then size and place it on the text where it needs to go.  I also use the worksheet/object protections to keep the text box to the correct size and position on the worksheet in case it changes.

Answer (score 1):

Tried all I could think of to no avail. Finally just merged the cells below that line for all but the column before and after the cell with the hyperlink. In the column with the hyperlink, the cell above had the hyperlink while the cell below just had plain text. Essentially that cell looks split. This might not work for everyone but the workaround worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If using LibreOffice Calc is an option, it supports this feature out of the box:

[image]

Simply edit the cell, highlight the text and open *Insert* → _Hyperlink... to place a link for the selected text:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Took me a bit, but I figured it out.

Right Click the Cell and Click "Format Cells"

This is what it was before, when the hyperlink applied to the whole cell, when the Text alignment - Horizontal, was set to "Left (Indent)":
[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa2bp.jpg)

**strong text**
When I changed the Horizontal setting from "Left (Indent)" to "General", the hyperlink only applied to the text.  Yay.

[image]

Comment: -1 Doesnt seem to be a general solution. Not sure how this was working for you, I tried many similar variations and had no luck.

Comment: -1 Doesn't seem to work for me as well.