# Excel 2007 - Hyperlink Text Within A Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, hyperlink

Is it possible to insert a hyperlink which affects text within a cell?

For example:

```
-----------------
| See this link | <-- Only the word "link" should be highlighted here.
-----------------
```

Before answering, please be aware of the following: I have seen many tutorials which use a formula `(="See this " &HYPERLINK("http://www.superuser.com","link"))` in order to insert a hyperlink already; I have 149 words within this cell, spaced out over many lines, and this method does not work with such a large amount of text as it exceeds 255 characters.

Many thanks.

Comment: as far as I tested - your example does not work, even for the small case. Have you tested it? Try this `="SeeThis"&HYPERLINK("http://www.superuser.com","link")` or even better - this way around `=HYPERLINK("http://www.superuser.com","link") & " SeeThis"`

Comment: Yes, of course I tested the example; it didn't work for me, either.  However, I did mention that this was a suggestion taken from a tutorial and was not exactly what I was looking for - it was more of a guide which indicates the type of solution that I am seeking.  Thank you for your suggestion; unfortunately, however, this also does not work.  There is no error message, but nothing actually happens either.  The further problem is that even if this smaller version were to work, it would not be suitable as my particular case deals with 149 words in total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by suggestions found on Super User and elsewhere, I have come to the conclusion that the only way to "achieve" the desired results is as follows:

Apply a link to the entire cell (which is the case whether we like it or not) and then to simply format the rest of the text - excluding the desired "link text" - to the standard format of the document, leaving the "link text" resembling a hyperlink.  Or, you could reverse the process and colour the "link text" to resemble a hyperlink, leaving the remainder of the text to follow the standard format set by the document.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you confirmed my suspicion and answered this already:

*If it does not work in the small example, it won't in the big.*

Here are some other related questions, which came to the conclusion, that it is not possible to solve this with excel in this exact way.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181995/create-a-hyperlink-within-an-excel-cell

[Hyperlinking a piece of text in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/428299/hyperlinking-a-piece-of-text-in-excel)